# okhttp interferes with bluetooth connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin.android, okhttp

I'm using okhttp library with my xamarin android app.  I just integrated from using system.net over to using okhttp for communicating with rest web service.  I noticed that if I'm using an active bluetooth scanner connection in my app, I cannot connect to the webservice, or if my service is communicating with the web service, I cannot make a bluetooth connection.

When trying to connect to the web service it results in java.IOException.

Is there a way to use both connections?

The bluetooth connection object is maintained in a public static class, where the okhttp connection is created and destroyed locally and nothing is maintained outside the scope of a single method.

Versions of libraries I'm using:
Visual Studio 2010.
xamarin.android: 4.20.0.28
okhttp: 2.4.0.2
tested with android 4.2.2 and 4.4.2

Comment: Any reason to why you are not using Xamarin.Android 5.1?

Comment: I'm careful about my library updates.  The project is deployed but still in active development.  I want to get to a point where I do some trunk refactoring and library updates, but I'm not ready to do that yet.